# Couple sum in array

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of integer says `[17, 1, 20, 4, 12, 9]` I want to get all the couple whose sum is 21.
for example in given array output should be like:

```
17,4
1,20
12,9
```

I could achieve the same using two loops. But the complexity goes N^2. Is there any efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can do it in O(n) using a hash set or O(n lg(n)) using a set.

Comment: Can you give a bit of logic

Comment: A generalized version of this question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720271/find-a-pair-of-elements-from-an-array-whose-sum-equals-a-given-number

Comment: Added a working solution for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HashSet`.

For example, put all the elements in a `HashSet` (single loop, O(N)).

Then iterate over the elements again, and for each element `i`, check if the `HashSet` contains `21-i`. That would also take O(N).

You can further optimize and do both steps in a single loop, but that won't change the asymptotic O(N) running time.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (set.contains(21 - arr[i])) {
        System.out.println(arr[i] + ", " + (21 - arr[i]));
    }
    set.add (arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: but the hashset contains method itself having O(N) complexity for each element

Comment: @Shadow No, `HashSet`'s `contains()` has expected O(1) complexity.

Comment: No, it is O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will print a number twice right?

Comment: 17,4
1,20
12,9
4,17
20,1
9,12

I hope the answer will print like this

Comment: @Shadow no. When you encounter the first number of a pair, the second number of the pair is not yet in the Set, so the pair is not printed until you encounter the second number.

Comment: One answer is output for `{20, 20, 1}`. But two answers for `{20, 1, 20}`.

Comment: @saka1029 in case of duplicates, you have to specify what's the desired behavior. If you want to always eliminate duplicates, it's possible to output the pair only if `arr[i]` is not yet in the Set. If you want to output duplicates, you can use a Map instead of Set and count the occurrences of each number.

Answer (score 3):

### Here is a piece of solution using python 3.0+.

You can do it in **O(N)** by using key-pair value data structure i.e. a dictionary.

Approach:

1. Loop once through the array and check if the result of value k subtracted from the current element i.e. *(k-arr[i])* is present in the dictionary means that the sum of the resultant value *k-arr[i]* and current element *arr[i]* equal to k. Add these two to the dictionary.
2. If *k-arr[i]* is not present in the dictionary then add the key arr[i] with value being *k-arr[i]*.
3. You may also add check for current element arr[i] being greater than k.

   ```
    def getPair(arr, k, dict):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if k - arr[i] in dict.keys():
                pass
                #print(arr[i], " ", (k-arr[i]))
            else:
                if k > arr[i]:
                    dict[arr[i]] = (k-arr[i])

    arr = [17, 1, 20, 4, 12, 9, 23]
    dict = {}
    getPair(arr, 21, dict)
    print("result: " , dict)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of working code with your example, using `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[]{17, 1, 20, 4, 12, 9};
        HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        int sum = 21;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            hash.add(arr[i]);
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(hash.contains(sum - arr[i])){
                System.out.println(arr[i] + " and " + (sum - arr[i]));
                hash.remove(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity is **O(n)**. The idea is to add all numbers of the array in the HashSet. Then, iterate through the array and check if, for each element `arr[i]`, `sum - arr[i]` is in the HashSet. If it is, it means you have a matching pair, so you remove one of the elements of the pair to avoid repeating matches.